# How to get data from service based from id?

Tags: angular

I dont know how to get data from service based on id in route on angular and need some help

this is my account.service.ts

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

export class AccountsService {
  
  
    accounts = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Master Account',
          age: 23,
          status: 'active'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Testaccount',
          age: 23,
          status: 'inactive'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Hidden Account',
          age: 23,
          status: 'unknown'
        }
      ];
      
  }

      
      getData(id: string) {
        
      }
}
```

This is my  component, in this part I can get the id but I don't know to get data from array in service based this id

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AccountsService } from 'src/app/account.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail-card',
  templateUrl: './detail-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail-card.component.css']
})
export class DetailCardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route:ActivatedRoute,
    private accountService:AccountsService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData()
  }

  getData(){
    const cardId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you service

```
  getData(id: string) {
    return this.accounts.find(x=> x.id == id)
  }
```

and in your component :

```
getData(){
const cardId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
const account = this.accountService.getData(cardId)
 console.log(account)
}
```

to render it inside the template

```
export class DetailCardComponent implements OnInit {
myaccount:any;
constructor(
private route:ActivatedRoute,
private accountService:AccountsService
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.getData()
}

getData(){
 const cardId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
 this.myaccount = this.accountService.getData(cardId)
 console.log(this.myaccount)
}

}
```

and inside your template :

```
<div >name is : {{myaccount?.name}} </div> 
<div >age is : {{myaccount?.age}} </div>
```

Comment: i can view when console.log, but do you know how to view it in component, because I cant call it in component

Comment: I edited answer and added new part for this

Answer (score 0):

inside the method `getData(id: number)` in the service put something like this:

`return this.accounts.find(acc => acc.id == id)`